# How can use mock on urllib2 so that no external call gets made and I can raise an exception on read()?

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

I'd like to raise `BadStatusLine` when read gets called. How can I accomplish that with [mock](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/)?

Answer (score 1):

I'd assign a `mock` object to `urllib2.open` like this:

```
from mock import Mock

import urllib2
import httplib

mock = Mock()
mock.return_value.read.side_effect = httplib.BadStatusLine('Mocked error')

urllib2.open = mock

response = urllib2.open()
response.read()
```

Note:

- `return_value` is used to access the mock object returned by `open()`
- `side_effect` is used to raise the desired exception when trying to execute `read()`